# Reading an attribute value from a NetCDF4 file with nested groups

Tags: r, netcdf4

This should be trivial but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this: I am trying to read an attribute value from a NetCDF4 file in R. Now, my NetCDF4 file (uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/95kwi8nxk9fprr2/S5P_NRTI_L2__NO2____20180728T130136_20180728T130636_04089_01_010100_20180728T140302.nc?dl=0)) is fairly complex, i.e. it contains nested groups.

I would like to extract the value of the attribute called `gml:posList` from the group `METADATA/EOP_METADATA/om:featureOfInterest/eop:multiExtentOf/gml:surfaceMembers/gml:exterior` using R. I am not sure if it matters in this context, but this group does not contain any variables, only metadata attributes.

I have tried the following

```
library(ncdf4)
fid = nc_open('S5P_NRTI_L2__NO2____20180728T130136_20180728T130636_04089_01_010100_20180728T140302.nc')
ncatt_get(fid, varid=0, attname='METADATA/EOP_METADATA/om:featureOfInterest/eop:multiExtentOf/gml:surfaceMembers/gml:exterior/gml:posList', verbose=TRUE)
```

but this returns

```
[1] "ncatt_get: entering"
[1] "ncatt_get: is a global att"
[1] "ncatt_get: calling ncatt_get_inner for a global att"
[1] "ncatt_get_inner: entering with ncid= 65536 varid= -1 attname= METADATA/EOP_METADATA/om:featureOfInterest/eop:multiExtentOf/gml:surfaceMembers/gml:exterior/gml:posList"
[1] "ncatt_get_inner: about to call R_nc4_inq_att"
[1] "ncatt_get_inner: R_nc4_inq_att returned with error= -43 type= -1"
$`hasatt`
[1] FALSE

$value
[1] 0
```

presumably indicating that it cannot find the attribute and I assume that I got the path wrong somehow.

**So my question is, how do I need to specify the path to an attribute that is a) in a nested group and b) not linked to a specific variable, such that ncatt_get() can find the attribute and return its value?**

By the way, just for reference, in Matlab the command

```
test = ncreadatt(file, 'METADATA/EOP_METADATA/om:featureOfInterest/eop:multiExtentOf/gml:surfaceMembers/gml:exterior', 'gml:posList')
```

works fine, so I know it's not an issue with the file.

Any hints would be highly appreciated!